# Criação XML para 'functionlist' do Notepad++ - Conforme Linguagem Criada Pelo Usuário

Tags: funções, notepad++

Estou realizando a criação de uma "Linguagem" no notepad++, para facilitar uma rotina que tenho no trabalho, consegui fazer a criação da linguagem, porém gostaria de estar criando uma "Lista de Funções" para essa minha linguagem.
Como tem a lista de funções referente à algumas linguagens existentes no Notepad++, como "XML", "Visual Basic", "JavaScript" dentre outras, quando estou realizando ajustes desses tipso de arquivos, e coloco para ativar o menu de "Lista de Funções", conforme a linguagem me aparecem as listas de funções.
Tentei realizar a criação do meu XMl de lista de funções para minha linguagem própria, conforme manual e passos disponíveis no site do Notepad++, ao realizar toda a criação e colocar esse arquivo XML na pasta do Notepad++, na pasta "functionList", ao fechar e abrir novamente o programa, abrir o arquivo que tenho da minha rotina de trabalho, e tentar abrir o menu de "Lista de Funções", não me apresenta nenhuma função criada dentro do arquivo.

Estarei informando abaixo, primeiro o arquivo criado de lista de funções e também o arquivo criado da minha linguagem, peço ajuda para avaliar o que posso estar fazendo errado para não apresentar as funções.

Lista de Função:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<NotepadPlus>
<functionList>
    <associationMap>
        <association id="eduardo.xml" userDefinedLangName="Eduardo"/>
    </associationMap>
    <parser
        displayName="Eduardo"
        id="eduardo"
        commentExpr="(/*([^]|[\r\n]|(*+([^/]|[\r\n])))*+/)|(//.)"
    >
        <function mainExpr="cargo\s*\([^\)\(]*\)[\n\s]*\{">
            <functionName>
                <nameExpr expr="cargo" />
            </functionName>
        </function>
        <function mainExpr="depto\s*\([^\)\(]*\)[\n\s]*\{">
            <functionName>
                <nameExpr expr="depto" />
            </functionName>
        </function>
        <function mainExpr="ccusto\s*\([^\)\(]*\)[\n\s]*\{">
            <functionName>
                <nameExpr expr="ccusto" />
            </functionName>
        </function>
        <function mainExpr="cate\s*\([^\)\(]*\)[\n\s]*\{">
            <functionName>
                <nameExpr expr="cate" />
            </functionName>
        </function>
        <function mainExpr="sind\s*\([^\)\(]*\)[\n\s]*\{">
            <functionName>
                <nameExpr expr="sind" />
            </functionName>
        </function>
        <function mainExpr="adm\s*\([^\)\(]*\)[\n\s]*\{">
            <functionName>
                <nameExpr expr="adm" />
            </functionName>
        </function>
    </parser>
</functionList>
```

Linguagem Própria

```
<NotepadPlus>
<UserLang name="Eduardo" ext="" udlVersion="2.1">
    <Settings>
        <Global caseIgnored="yes" allowFoldOfComments="no" foldCompact="yes" forcePureLC="0" decimalSeparator="0" />
        <Prefix Keywords1="no" Keywords2="no" Keywords3="yes" Keywords4="no" Keywords5="no" Keywords6="no" Keywords7="no" Keywords8="no" />
    </Settings>
    <KeywordLists>
        <Keywords name="Comments">00/* 01 02*/ 03 04</Keywords>
        <Keywords name="Numbers, prefix1"></Keywords>
        <Keywords name="Numbers, prefix2"></Keywords>
        <Keywords name="Numbers, extras1"></Keywords>
        <Keywords name="Numbers, extras2"></Keywords>
        <Keywords name="Numbers, suffix1"></Keywords>
        <Keywords name="Numbers, suffix2"></Keywords>
        <Keywords name="Numbers, range"></Keywords>
        <Keywords name="Operators1">; ( )</Keywords>
        <Keywords name="Operators2">+ - * / == =&gt; =&lt; &gt; &lt; &lt;&gt;</Keywords>
        <Keywords name="Folders in code1, open">para</Keywords>
        <Keywords name="Folders in code1, middle"></Keywords>
        <Keywords name="Folders in code1, close">fimpara</Keywords>
        <Keywords name="Folders in code2, open">se</Keywords>
        <Keywords name="Folders in code2, middle"></Keywords>
        <Keywords name="Folders in code2, close">fimse</Keywords>
        <Keywords name="Folders in comment, open"></Keywords>
        <Keywords name="Folders in comment, middle"></Keywords>
        <Keywords name="Folders in comment, close"></Keywords>
        <Keywords name="Keywords1">cargo&#x000D;&#x000A;depto&#x000D;&#x000A;ccusto&#x000D;&#x000A;cate&#x000D;&#x000A;sind&#x000D;&#x000A;adm&#x000D;&#x000A;admtransf&#x000D;&#x000A;salar&#x000D;&#x000A;salario&#x000D;&#x000A;vhora&#x000D;&#x000A;vdia&#x000D;&#x000A;vmes&#x000D;&#x000A;hmes&#x000D;&#x000A;hsem&#x000D;&#x000A;hdia&#x000D;&#x000A;salmin&#x000D;&#x000A;psal&#x000D;&#x000A;nfil&#x000D;&#x000A;ndep&#x000D;&#x000A;diasmes&#x000D;&#x000A;diastrab&#x000D;&#x000A;novant&#x000D;&#x000A;anostra&#x000D;&#x000A;basedsr&#x000D;&#x000A;compatual&#x000D;&#x000A;bc&#x000D;&#x000A;nascimento&#x000D;&#x000A;idade&#x000D;&#x000A;percadicnoturno&#x000D;&#x000A;salariobase&#x000D;&#x000A;salariocontratual&#x000D;&#x000A;vbasecalc&#x000D;&#x000A;vpercent&#x000D;&#x000A;diasfaltadsr&#x000D;&#x000A;valvar&#x000D;&#x000A;valeve&#x000D;&#x000A;evtaxa&#x000D;&#x000A;exibe&#x000D;&#x000A;trazdia&#x000D;&#x000A;trazmes&#x000D;&#x000A;trazano&#x000D;&#x000A;dmdata&#x000D;&#x000A;somadia&#x000D;&#x000A;tiradia&#x000D;&#x000A;addmes&#x000D;&#x000A;submes&#x000D;&#x000A;arrend&#x000D;&#x000A;valorha&#x000D;&#x000A;heferiado&#x000D;&#x000A;diasemana&#x000D;&#x000A;qtdfermes&#x000D;&#x000A;semanames&#x000D;&#x000A;tprov&#x000D;&#x000A;tdesc&#x000D;&#x000A;tliqu&#x000D;&#x000A;calculo&#x000D;&#x000A;refeve&#x000D;&#x000A;pprov&#x000D;&#x000A;pdesc&#x000D;&#x000A;pliqu&#x000D;&#x000A;qtdfilho&#x000D;&#x000A;qtddep&#x000D;&#x000A;taxairrf&#x000D;&#x000A;dedirrf&#x000D;&#x000A;descdep&#x000D;&#x000A;minirrf&#x000D;&#x000A;diasdsr&#x000D;&#x000A;sindicalizado&#x000D;&#x000A;psalcod&#x000D;&#x000A;ndepirrf&#x000D;&#x000A;calcmedia&#x000D;&#x000A;mediasdsrhora&#x000D;&#x000A;datarescisao&#x000D;&#x000A;qtdedsrperiodo&#x000D;&#x000A;databasesindicato&#x000D;&#x000A;nascimentodependente&#x000D;&#x000A;sexo&#x000D;&#x000A;vbaseint&#x000D;&#x000A;situacao&#x000D;&#x000A;fersemana&#x000D;&#x000A;qtdiastrabperiodo&#x000D;&#x000A;semanamestrab&#x000D;&#x000A;diassituacao&#x000D;&#x000A;qtddependente&#x000D;&#x000A;datavantagem</Keywords>
        <Keywords name="Keywords2">valor</Keywords>
        <Keywords name="Keywords3">vcalc&#x000D;&#x000A;vinf&#x000D;&#x000A;se&#x000D;&#x000A;e&#x000D;&#x000A;ou&#x000D;&#x000A;senao&#x000D;&#x000A;para&#x000D;&#x000A;de&#x000D;&#x000A;ate&#x000D;&#x000A;fimpara&#x000D;&#x000A;fimse</Keywords>
        <Keywords name="Keywords4"></Keywords>
        <Keywords name="Keywords5"></Keywords>
        <Keywords name="Keywords6"></Keywords>
        <Keywords name="Keywords7"></Keywords>
        <Keywords name="Keywords8"></Keywords>
        <Keywords name="Delimiters">00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23</Keywords>
    </KeywordLists>
    <Styles>
        <WordsStyle name="DEFAULT" fgColor="FFFFFF" bgColor="FFFFFF" colorStyle="1" fontStyle="0" nesting="0" />
        <WordsStyle name="COMMENTS" fgColor="77A279" bgColor="FFFFFF" colorStyle="1" fontStyle="0" nesting="0" />
        <WordsStyle name="LINE COMMENTS" fgColor="E4BABA" bgColor="FFFFFF" colorStyle="1" fontStyle="0" nesting="0" />
        <WordsStyle name="NUMBERS" fgColor="FFFFFF" bgColor="FFFFFF" colorStyle="1" fontStyle="0" nesting="0" />
        <WordsStyle name="KEYWORDS1" fgColor="510000" bgColor="FFFFFF" colorStyle="1" fontStyle="3" nesting="0" />
        <WordsStyle name="KEYWORDS2" fgColor="242400" bgColor="242424" colorStyle="1" fontStyle="3" nesting="0" />
        <WordsStyle name="KEYWORDS3" fgColor="000000" bgColor="FFFFFF" colorStyle="1" fontStyle="1" nesting="0" />
        <WordsStyle name="KEYWORDS4" fgColor="000000" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontStyle="0" nesting="0" />
        <WordsStyle name="KEYWORDS5" fgColor="000000" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontStyle="0" nesting="0" />
        <WordsStyle name="KEYWORDS6" fgColor="000000" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontStyle="0" nesting="0" />
        <WordsStyle name="KEYWORDS7" fgColor="000000" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontStyle="0" nesting="0" />
        <WordsStyle name="KEYWORDS8" fgColor="000000" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontStyle="0" nesting="0" />
        <WordsStyle name="OPERATORS" fgColor="7A7A3D" bgColor="FFFFFF" colorStyle="1" fontStyle="0" nesting="0" />
        <WordsStyle name="FOLDER IN CODE1" fgColor="000000" bgColor="FFFFFF" colorStyle="1" fontStyle="1" nesting="0" />
        <WordsStyle name="FOLDER IN CODE2" fgColor="000000" bgColor="FFFFFF" colorStyle="1" fontStyle="1" nesting="0" />
        <WordsStyle name="FOLDER IN COMMENT" fgColor="648869" bgColor="FFFFFF" colorStyle="1" fontStyle="1" nesting="0" />
        <WordsStyle name="DELIMITERS1" fgColor="000080" bgColor="FFFFFF" colorStyle="1" fontStyle="0" nesting="1024" />
        <WordsStyle name="DELIMITERS2" fgColor="88AC8C" bgColor="FFFFFF" colorStyle="1" fontStyle="0" nesting="0" />
        <WordsStyle name="DELIMITERS3" fgColor="000000" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontStyle="0" nesting="0" />
        <WordsStyle name="DELIMITERS4" fgColor="000000" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontStyle="0" nesting="0" />
        <WordsStyle name="DELIMITERS5" fgColor="000000" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontStyle="0" nesting="0" />
        <WordsStyle name="DELIMITERS6" fgColor="000000" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontStyle="0" nesting="0" />
        <WordsStyle name="DELIMITERS7" fgColor="000000" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontStyle="0" nesting="0" />
        <WordsStyle name="DELIMITERS8" fgColor="000000" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontStyle="0" nesting="0" />
    </Styles>
</UserLang>
```

Grato desde já!

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: Não compreendi esse comentário, resumi com detalhes suficientes o meu problema